# Add [drivers] as synonym for [driver]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I think [drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drivers) tag should be used as synonym for [driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/driver) tag. 
Because they could be used interchangeable completely.

Currently there are 656 questions tagged [drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drivers) and 3,940 tagged [driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/driver).

I no see any reason to leave them separated.

They should be merged.

Comment: You make some powerful arguments for making that synonym. I'm convinced.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan do you see any reason to leave them separated?

Comment: You are making a request for someone else to do something. It's up to you to make the case that they *should* do this thing, not for me to make the case that it should *not* be done.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan question updated.